# The requested resource / was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, cloud9-ide

I have created a `Laravel Framework 5.5.22` project on `c9`. I am using the php version:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.0.25-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2017 14:07:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.25-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

When I run the php built in server I get the error `No such file or directory`:

```
Starting PHP built-in web server, serving https://projet-laravel-testuser.c9users.io/.
PHP 7.0.25-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Development Server started at Thu Nov 30 17:36:08 2017
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
Document root is /home/ubuntu/workspace
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Thu Nov 30 17:36:16 2017] 10.240.0.100:38766 [404]: / - No such file or directory
```

I also tested apache2:

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Sep 18 2017 16:37:54
```

However, here I only get a `blank` page back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I set:

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-cloud9.conf`
and added `/public` to the end of line 2.

It looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/public
```

Comment: Does `/home/ubuntu/workspace` exist?

Comment: My user path on c9 is: `admin:~/workspace (master) $ pwd
/home/ubuntu/workspace`

Comment: Are you serving from the Laravel project's root, or from the project's "public" folder? It should be the latter.

Comment: @ChrisForrence How to verify this?

Comment: When you started up the built-in server, what was the full command you used?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Good question, I am currently trying to figure out how to see on c9 the full server command... Please also see my updated answer for configuring the c9 config file.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I use `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080`

Comment: OK, add `-t public/` to that. Out of curiosity, are you starting it up with "Run Project"?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Nice, now I get a real error: `No application encryption key has been specified.` Please add your comment as an answer and also explain me why this is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you start up the built-in server, it looks like it's running in the project root. You can specify a `-t` flag to tell PHP to run the server from a different folder:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/
```

Don't forget to call `php artisan key:generate` and to fill out your `.env` file if needed!

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to not finding the right resource folder/file. You have to make sure that when you start server you are on the right directory where the project was stored. So the solution is:

```
cd your/folder/project
```

and then

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public/
```

Hope it helps. Thank you.